TypeScript Type Inference of result after narrowing
I'm trying to make TypeScript correctly infer the return type of a function (the result) based on the context in which it was called.
TS correctly infers the result as 'isA' | 'isB' because the input is a parameter.
However I'd hope TS to narrow down the type of the result after I narrow the possibilities with a conditional.
Naive approach:
function matchType1<A, B>(
  type: "a" | "b",
  fns: { onA: () => A; onB: () => B }
) {
  return type === "a" ? fns.onA() : fns.onB()
}

Object-Wrapped approach:
function matchType2<A, B>(
  type: "a" | "b",
  fns: { onA: () => A; onB: () => B}
) {
  return type === "a" 
    ? { a: fns.onA() }
    : { b: fns.onB() }
}

Overloaded function approach:
function matchType3<A, B>(type: "a", fns: { onA: () => A; onB: () => B }): A;
function matchType3<A, B>(type: "b", fns: { onA: () => A; onB: () => B }): B;
function matchType3<A, B>(
  type: "a" | "b",
  fns: { onA: () => A; onB: () => B }
) {
  return type === "a" ? fns.onA() : fns.onB();
}

Usage:
async function main(type: "a" | "b") {
  const promise1 = matchType1(type, {
    onA: () => Promise.resolve("isA" as const),
    onB: () => Promise.resolve("isB" as const),
  });

  const promise2 = matchType2(type, {
    onA: () => Promise.resolve("isA" as const),
    onB: () => Promise.resolve("isB" as const),
  });

  const promise3 = matchType3(type, { // error (TS 2769) passing type as there is no overload for 'a' | 'b'
    onA: () => Promise.resolve("isA" as const),
    onB: () => Promise.resolve("isB" as const),
    });

  const [result1, result2, result3] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);

  if (type === "a") {
    const data1 = result1; // Inferred as "isA" | "isB"
    const data2 = result2[type]; // inferred as Promise<"isA"> | undefined
    const data3 = result3; // correctly inferred as 'isA' but there is an error on the call to matchType3 
  }


Considerations
Part of the problem is that the conditional narrowing the type happens after I call matchType*. Placing the call inside the conditional if (type === 'a') { works as expected. However that doesn't fulfil my needs.
TS errors:
For matchType3, with function overloading the error is
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "a", fns: { onA: () => Promise<"isA">; onB: () => Promise<"isB">; }): Promise<"isA">', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'.
      Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: "b", fns: { onA: () => Promise<"isA">; onB: () => Promise<"isB">; }): Promise<"isB">', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b"'.
      Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.(2769)


Workarounds
const data2 = result2[type] is not terrible as it already knows it's either Promise<"isA"> or undefined so I could exclude the undefined
const data2 = result2[type]!

Of course I'd like not to. This is a challenge now.
I did also try with conditional return types, but same result.
Playground
You can check all the code above in the TS playground; https://tsplay.dev/ND0yVN

The generic A and B stuff is really making this more complex than it should be for a [mre]. I suggest replacing your code with this version instead so we can focus on the (impossible, I think) task you're trying to perform.

(see prev comment, pls)  TS can't keep track of all possible narrowings, or go back and narrow based on new information. It isn't a proof solver; narrowing happens only in specific scenarios.  The closest you can get to what you're doing is to pass the state you're checking through the function, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Good one! the only downside I can see is that for multiple results as it's my case I would need to check the type on all of them in the conditional. I tried with .every and a type guard but it isn't enough; https://tsplay.dev/N7d1Dm

And is that really in scope here? Your multiple results in the question seemed to be an exploration of multiple approaches. If that's important, please [edit] to make that clear.  But as far as I know there's no way for every() to type guard a tuple the way you need it, so unless you repackage the multiple results in a single result, you'll have to do multiple checks.  How should I proceed here with an answer?  And please respond regarding removing the distracting A, B generics.

It's difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve, however, i will do my best to answer the issues raised:
const promise3 = matchType3(type, {
    onA: () => Promise.resolve("isA" as const),
    onB: () => Promise.resolve("isB" as const),
});

TypeScript infers the type parameter as: (parameter) type: "a" | "b".
In TypeScript function overload approach, functions have an implementation signature, but this signature cannot be called directly. Essentially, when you call a function, you're actually calling one of the overload signatures. So, if you pass a union type that doesn't match any of the overload signatures, TypeScript will throw an error.
What you can do to narrow the possibility in the case of matchType2, following your example in https://tsplay.dev/ND0yVN, is you can use a built-in utility of TypeScript, in this case a NonNullable utility.
type Type = NonNullable<typeof result2[typeof type]>; // type Type = Promise<"isA">
const data2: "isA" =  await (result2[type] as Type).then((data) => data);

